# jQuery only works with hover

Tags: jquery

I have a question regarding jQuery.

Please see the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".button" ).hover(function() {
        $('.div1').animate({width: '200px'});
    }, function() {
        $('.div1').animate({width: '100px'});
    });
});
```

Basically what it does is this: when a user hovers a div - its width goes up to 200px. When the user moves his mouse away then the width goes back to normal.

I was wondering why isn't this working with .click?

Comment: click doesnt have the mouseout event

Comment: Yes I know, sorry for no being clear. I want to make an effect where you click and the width goes up to 200. Then you click again and the width goes back to normal.

Comment: for click, i can suggest you mousedown and mouseup events ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can make it like this :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".button").on('click', function() {
    var toggleWidth = $(".div1").width() == 100 ? 200 : 100;
    $('.div1').animate({
      width: toggleWidth
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1"></div>


<button class="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: Just a minor thing, when clicking during the closing animation, it will not reopen.

Answer (score 1):

achieve with class

```
$(".button").on("click" , function() {

        if(!$(this).hasClass("clikedButton")){
           $('.div1').animate({width: '200px'});
           $(this).addClass("clikedButton");
        }
        else{
           $('.div1').animate({width: '100px'});
           $(this).removeClass("clikedButton")
        }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2h6yao9b/)

Answer (score 0):

please check this code:

```
<h1>Mouse Click</h1>
    <ul class="mouseClick">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
    </ul>

       function ShowLi() {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
        return false;
    }


    $('.mouseClick li').click(ShowLi);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNQnM/35/)

Comment: You need to add some code if you want to share jsfiddle link :)

Answer (score 0):

`.hover` is not an event in jQuery, it's a shortcut. Basically, it's like writing

```
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```

`.click` used to have that kind of shortcut with `.toggle(handler1, handler2)` but it has been deprecated and removed.

You need to use a flag. I prefer to insert that flag in the data object. Just do something like that :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".button" ).click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data("click_toggle", !$this.data("click_toggle"));
        $('.div1').animate({width: $this.data("click_toggle") ? '200px' : '100px'});
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2h6yao9b/1/)

---

The flag can also be a class that you toggle with `toggleClass` and check if the element has the class with `.hasClass`.

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('active');
    $('.div1').animate({width: $this.hasClass("active") ? '200px' : '100px'});
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2h6yao9b/2/)

---

Lastly, you could use CSS animation. You just have to toggle the class and use CSS to animate the width. Depending on your markup though, you may have to use different DOM traversal methods, but here an example :

**HTML**

```
<div class="div1"></div>


<button class="button">Click</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('active');
    //If you have a single div1, you can use $('.div1').toggleClass('active');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.div1{

    width:100px;
    background:green;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transition : all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition : all 0.5s;
    -o-transition : all 0.5s;
    transition : all 0.5s;
}

.div1.active{
    width : 200px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2h6yao9b/3/)